# julia dataframe - subsetting column by list of values

Tags: dataframe, subset, julia, data-manipulation

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B = 2:2:20)

10x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 1  | 2  |
| 2   | 2  | 4  |
| 3   | 3  | 6  |
| 4   | 4  | 8  |
| 5   | 5  | 10 |
...
...
```

is it possible to subset dataframe by using a list of values, something like

```
df[df[:A] .in [3,4], :]
```

if the list is small, this can by done by

```
df[(df[:A] .== 3) |  (df[:A] .== 4), :]
```

but I am wondering if there is way to do this for large list of values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vectorized "in" function in julia?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661315/vectorized-in-function-in-julia)

Comment: `df[ [x in [3,4] for x in df[:A]] ,:]` is one equivalent. Easy to adapt to other sets and conditions.

Comment: Matt B's vectorin function is incredibly useful and the double array comprehension is not very intuitive for new julia users.  I think it should be added to Base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = 1:3:30, y = [2, 1, 2,1,3,4,5,3,3,3])
10x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | x  | y |
|-----|----|---|
| 1   | 1  | 2 |
| 2   | 4  | 1 |
| 3   | 7  | 2 |
| 4   | 10 | 1 |
| 5   | 13 | 3 |
| 6   | 16 | 4 |
| 7   | 19 | 5 |
| 8   | 22 | 3 |
| 9   | 25 | 3 |
| 10  | 28 | 3 |

julia> df[findin(df[:y],[1,3]),:]
6x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | x  | y |
|-----|----|---|
| 1   | 4  | 1 |
| 2   | 10 | 1 |
| 3   | 13 | 3 |
| 4   | 22 | 3 |
| 5   | 25 | 3 |
| 6   | 28 | 3 |
```

Comment: `ERROR: UndefVarError: findin not defined`

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer above does not work anymore.
So here is something working in 2019:

```
# by column name

julia> df[ [x in [3,4] for x in df[:A]] ,:]
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 3     │ 6     │
│ 2   │ 4     │ 8     │

# or by column number

julia> df[ [x in [3,4] for x in df[:1]] ,:]
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 3     │ 6     │
│ 2   │ 4     │ 8     │
```