# Negation of condition when subsetting in Julia

Tags: dataframe, subset, julia, data-manipulation

I want to subset dataframe in Julia. I have DataArrays.DataArray{String,1} named "brokenDf" which contains serial id that I want to remove from dataframe and dataframe "df".

The closest I've got is "findin"

`df[findin(df[:serial],brokenDf),:];`

but I don't know how I can flip it over after this or if we have `NOT IN` command in Julia. So, it would work like `findNOTin()`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You could use `df[map(x -> !(x in broken), df[:serial]), :]`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661315/vectorized-in-function-in-julia/29661623#29661623 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405048/how-to-index-all-but-select-indices/39405954#39405954

Comment: 2nd link in @MattB.'s comment suggests `df[setdiff(df[:serial],brokenDF),:]`

Comment: @ niczky12 I like the idea that you came up with. However, `map(x -> !(x in broken), df[:serial])` returns DataArrays.DataArray{Any,1} rather than `DataArrays.DataArray{Bool,1}`. As a result, it caused the whole thing raised `MethodError: no method matching getindex(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Any,1}, ::Colon)`. I tried to wrap it with `convert(Bool, ...)` which didn't work either.

Comment: @Dan Getz I also like your answer but `setdiff(df[:serial],brokenDF)` return `Array{String,1}` which made the entire thing to raise `MethodError: no method matching getindex(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Array{String,1}, ::Colon)`

Comment: That seems like a missing functionality from DataFrames to be honest. Anyway, you can wrap the thing in a Bool constructor like this: `df[DataArray{Bool}(map(x -> !(x in broken), df[:serial])),:]`. This should work.

Comment: @niczky12 Thank you for your help. It works now if you can write your solution to an answer, I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use `map()` and and create a `Bool` array to subset the rows of your dataframe:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(serial = 1:6, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M", "N", "N"]);

broken = [1,2,5];

df[DataArray{Bool}(map(x -> !(x in broken), df[:serial])),:]
```

The output is:

```
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ serial │ B   │
├─────┼────────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 3      │ "F" │
│ 2   │ 4      │ "M" │
│ 3   │ 6      │ "N" │
```

Note that `!` negates your boolean condition, so `!true == false`.

Answer (score 1):

The below should do what you want:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:6, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M", "N", "N"]);

# Rows where B .== "M"
f1 = find(df[:, 2] .== "M");

# Rows where B is not "M"
f2 = find(df[:, 2] .!= "M");

# Rows where B is not "M" and is not "F"
f3 = reduce(&, (df[:, 2] .!= "F", df[:, 2] .!= "M"));
```

The latter can be automated writing a function:

```
# Define function
function find_is_not(x, conditions)
    temp = sum(x .!= conditions, 2);
    res  = find(temp .== length(conditions));
    return res;
end

# Rows where B is not "M" and is not "F" (with find_is_not)
f4 = find_is_not(df[:, 2], ["M" "F"]);
```

Comment: I think the last line with `.==2` could be bit more readable by using boolean `&` (`AND`) operator, like this: `reduce(&, (df[:, 2] .!= "F",df[:, 2] .!= "M"))`. Maybe this could be used to improve the proposed function as well?

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right, I am editing my comment.

Comment: Don't want to steal your answer, but I think the simple `map` solution I proposed as comment is a lot simpler than what you're doing here.

Comment: You can certainly do it in different ways, map is a good alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm very new to Julia but I gave your solution a go although I'm not sure what's going on the the function. Unfortunately, your function returned nothing for my actual dataframe.

Comment: @bensw there was a mistake in the last line of the answer. The function is expecting `x` (a `DataArrays.DataArray{String,1}`) and conditions (a `1×k Array{String,2}` where `k` is the number of conditions you are checking). The first line of the function is checking (for each condition) when `x` is not equal to it. `x .!= conditions` returns a `n×k DataArrays.DataArray{Bool,2}` where `true` identifies the `is not` condition. When you sum it up on the second dimension you get a `DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,2}`. The values in each lines are the number of times the `is not` condition is verified.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time explaining but I've sill got this error `DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")`

Comment: @bensw can you post a link to a JLD with your data?

Comment: @ merch I'm afraid that I cannot hand you data as it's confidential for my company. But the idea was I read data in `df = readtable("data.csv");` subseting it `dfB = df[(df[:mode] .== "B"),:serial];`. At this point, I would have DataArrays.DataArray{String,1}. And now I wanted to use dfB to subset my df dataframe and naget it. That is all. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using list comprehension would be:

```
df = df[[!(i in brokenDf) for i in df.serial], :]
```

which will give you the filtered DataFrame where `df.serial` is not in `brokenDf`.