# Find rows where column values are in set (similar to pandas isin or R %in%)

Tags: dataframe, julia

```
using CSV, DataFrames
iris = CSV.read(joinpath(dirname(pathof(DataFrames)),"..","test/data/iris.csv"))

head(iris)
6×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ SepalLength │ SepalWidth │ PetalLength │ PetalWidth │ Species │
│     │ Float64⍰    │ Float64⍰   │ Float64⍰    │ Float64⍰   │ String⍰ │
├─────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 5.1         │ 3.5        │ 1.4         │ 0.2        │ setosa  │
│ 2   │ 4.9         │ 3.0        │ 1.4         │ 0.2        │ setosa  │
│ 3   │ 4.7         │ 3.2        │ 1.3         │ 0.2        │ setosa  │
│ 4   │ 4.6         │ 3.1        │ 1.5         │ 0.2        │ setosa  │
│ 5   │ 5.0         │ 3.6        │ 1.4         │ 0.2        │ setosa  │
│ 6   │ 5.4         │ 3.9        │ 1.7         │ 0.4        │ setosa  │
```

I want to find all rows where Species is in `setosa` or `virginica`. Note that the answer must use a lookup into an array of values to find since I want the result to work when looking for arbitrarily many values.

---

There is a function called indexin. It gets me halfway there:

```
iris[indexin(iris.Species ,["setosa", "virginica"])]
```

But when I try to use it for indexing the result is:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: Only Integer values allowed when indexing by vector of numbers
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iris[ in.(iris[:Species],(["virginica","setosa"],)),: ]
```

The additional `tuple` around `["virginica","setosa"]` allows to avoid broadcasting over the search list.

Comment: Ah, that is kinda ugly, but I guess those kinks will be ironed out eventually :) Thanks

Comment: A more Julian approach would be to write `filter(x -> x[:Species] in ["virginica", "setosa"], iris)`. If you use DataFramesMeta this is what you can alternatively use `@where(iris, in.(:Species, [["virginica", "setosa"]]))`.

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve this is to use `findall`:

```
iris[findall(in(["setosa", "virginica"]), iris.Species), :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `findin` function.

```
iris[findin(iris[:Species],["setosa","virginica"]),:]
```

Note that if you want to use `findin` to search only one value, it has to be always an array, like

```
iris[findin(iris[:Species],["setosa"]),:]
```

Comment: `findin` is deprecated in 0.7 and removed from 1.0. `findall(in(...), ...)` replaces it.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after posting this answer... Thanks for the heads up anyway :)